# MongoDb sort Collection by count in other Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting

I have two collections: `collection A` and `collection B`. Collection B "A_id" will have the _id from Collection A (kinda like a relationship).

Collection A

```
{
  _id,
  name
}
```

Collection B

```
{
 _id,
 A_id,
 other_id
}
```

I need to sort the documents from Collection A by the amount of repetitions of documents to an A_id in Collection B (sort by count if you may). The constraint is that we don't want to have an array in collection A because the documents in B will grow a lot and will be updated constantly.

Any idea how to perform this kind of sorting?

Thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you're asking.  You have to know some things about the data first.   How many documents will a B document have?

- It looks like a case where you'd want Collection A to have an items field with documents that are B.  There is a 16 MB limit for that, but for most cases works just fine.
- Keep a count on A with numbers of B records inserted.  (Ie every time you insert a B you'd `$inc` the field on A).  You'd then do an index on the count field for A and do `sort({count: -1})`

Comment: Thanks! Went with option 2 in the end. The count and using $inc

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that this is not strictly possible. However, you could use the [aggregation framework group function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and $sum accumulator to group by A_id which will give you a mapping between A_id and the total number of documents in collection B with that A_id. Sort that mapping and then you can select things from collection A in the order you have described, although you'd have to select from collection A one at a time since you are enforcing an ordering at selection time.

The other option would be to have some count field in collection A on each document that you include logic to [increment](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) every time something is inserted into in collection B with a particular A_id.

Comment: The first option just inspired me on a similar problem at hand since I can't change data schema. A little improvement: we don't have to select one at a time. We can sort the result selected from A by the order of `A_id`s we just calculated with B.